# MSYS vs. MinGW: internal environment variables

Tags: mingw, msys, mingw-w64, msys2

MSYS2 default shell (bash) can be started  choosing among three launchers, which also set the  environment variable `MSYSTEM`.   Specifically:

1. `msys2_shell.bat` sets it to  `MSYS`
2. `mingw64_shell.bat` sets it to   `MINGW64` and
3. `mingw32_shell.bat` sets it to `MINGW32`.

Apart from the shells' prompt, the visible differences are:

- There is an equivalent  shell variable `$MSYSTEM` exported;
- `uname` output is based on `$MSYSTEM`;
- When `$MSYSTEM` is  `MINGW*`, `/mingw*/bin` is the first path in `$PATH`.

Assuming we have `/usr/bin/gcc`, `/mingw64/bin/gcc`,  `/mingw32/bin/gcc`, a sensible consequence of  the set value of `$MSYSTEM` is that we will use a different compiler generating a different binary (POSIX or native 32/64).

- What are other significant differences determined by `$MSYSTEM` value?
- Are there any binaries that make a specific use of this variable?
- Is `pacman` affected by the subsystem?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The following is extracted from a [post](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/discussion/general/thread/b7dfdac8/#3939) by Ray Donnelly, a  MinGW-w64 contributor. It enlightens on the subject and is essential preamble to my question.

> There are 3 systems, MSYS2 and 32-bit and 64-bit Native Windows systems. Each system has its own repository of software packages in the MSYS2 distribution. [...] that is an important distinction between them. MSYS2 implements a POSIX-y FHS filesystem namespace and that's very important for lots of things.
>   [...]
>   The MinGW-w64 32-bit and 64-bit systems are Native Windows software which are rooted at /mingw32 and /mingw64 respectively. It's not like we replaced every Linux API call ourselves; most of the upstream projects do this work for us since they already provide Windows ports, but yes sometimes we have to do it. We also add special relocation patches to a lot of the software so that you are free to install the root the whole thing (e.g. C:\msys64) wherever you want. MSYS2 software doesn't need these patches (since the Native Windows location is a hidden installation detail) but MinGW-w64 software often does.
>   [F]rom an end user perspective, there's only 2 systems, MSYS2 and the XX-bit Native Windows one, and yes, some packages exist for both those systems. Specifically, MSYS2 exists to run development tools necessary to build Native Windows software, so if a build system needs an MSYS2 version of Python or Perl to operate correctly (because it assumes FHS or whatever) then we need to provide those packages. We never add MSYS2 packages without making sure there is a need for them. If you don't know that you need the MSYS2 version of something, then install the appropriate Native Windows one instead.
>   An example of when you will need MSYS2 Python is if you try to use Google's repo tools. This is because repo uses the fcntl Python module and that module only exists on POSIX-y systems. IMHO Python is doing a bad job of abstracting the OSes here and that's a fundamental thing that a scripting language should do, and fcntl (and pyWin32) should not exist, but I'm not the boss of Python.
>   Fortunately, Pacman has dependency management and will install the stuff needed for whatever packages you are actually interested in.
>   GNU Autotools will never work well except via a FHS compliant system with a POSIX shell, and this naturally leads to other tools needing to exist in the same filesystem namespace, such as make, perl, m4, bison, flex etc etc.

Given Ray Donnelly post, what makes up a system is first and foremost the `PATH` variable, because, depending on directory priorities Google's repo tools will be built with MSYS2 or MinGW packages.
In fact the `shell` script, which switches between MSYS2 and  MinGW shells, exports the environment variable `MSYSTEM` with its argument `mingw32|mingw64|msys` and sources `/etc/profile`. The latter, in turn, sets the `PATH` based on  the value of `MSYSTEM`. By and large for MSYS2 the `PATH` is
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`, while for MinGW 64 it is `/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`, therefore running the  `gcc` compilers will execute  MSYS2 or MinGW version accordingly.
There are other minor env. variables too, for example `MANPATH` to read the proper manuals, once the proper binaries are called, or `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to read the proper lib files, when building.

As regards, `pacman` it is not totally true that it is not affected, as from @David Grayson comment.
MSYS2  [wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/wiki/MSYS2%20introduction/) vaguely affirms that:

> Use msys2 shell for running pacman, makepkg, makepkg-mingw and for building POSIX-dependent software that you don't intend to distribute. Use mingw shells for building native software and other tasks.

Ray Donnelly clarifies the things again in another [post](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/discussion/general/thread/dcf8f4d3/#5d86) :

> Generally speaking, you can use any shell for pacman, but you could run into some issues using mingw shells where depending on what packages you've installed into /mingw32 or /mingw64, the post install scripts of packages (which are arbitrary bash scripts) may end up running an unexpected mingw-w64 variant of a program. A concrete example of that would be 'sed'. So running pacman from msys2_shell.bat avoids a class of potential problems (though we'd try to fix any that are reported anyway).

Summing up:

*What are other significant differences determined by `$MSYSTEM` value?*
The immediate significant differences are in the related  values of the path variables identified by  @David Grayson.

*Are there any binaries that make a specific use of this variable?*
It seems safe to say that there is no specific binary reading directly `$MSYSTEM`, but a great deal of software use/read the path variables above based on `$MSYSTEM`.

*Is `pacman` affected by the subsystem?*
Yes.

Comment: Nowadays, https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-introduction/#subsystems and https://www.msys2.org/wiki/How-does-MSYS2-differ-from-Cygwin/#packages are also helpful.

Answer (score 15):

The intention behind the three choices was to give you the option of two different development environments:

1. MinGW: intended for development of native Windows applications.  This is further divided into:

   - Mingw32 for producing 32 bit executables, and of course
   - Mingw64 for producing 64 bit executables

   Think of this as where you will do your end-user development.  Software that won't normally be run inside of the MSYS2 environment itself.
2. MSYS: intended to build applications that will operate in a posix-y environment with FHS style filesystem naming.  Think of this as where you will do development for the tools that are actually running inside Msys2.  Or, you can think of this like you would Cygwin.

You can get more information on this subject in [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/discussion/general/thread/b7dfdac8/?limit=25#6c41) on the MSYS2 sourceforge forum.

Comment: I was already aware of this, which does not specifically answer my question. Anyway  Ray Donnelly link does.

Answer (score 6):

You should look in `/etc/profile` (which comes from [this file on GitHub](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/blob/master/filesystem/profile)).  There you can see that `MSYSTEM` affects:

- `PATH`
- `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`
- `ACLOCAL_PATH`
- `MANPATH`
- `MINGW_MOUNT_POINT`

Also, there is a [pull request](https://github.com/Alexpux/MSYS2-packages/pull/612/files) that adds `/etc/profile/msystem`, which would be a script that sets additional variables based on `MSYSTEM`.

Comment: This means that, during the make process, `pkg-config` and `automake` can look for `.pc` and `.m4`  files in `/mingwXX` rather than `/usr`. This should affect also `pacman` build process too. So will the output of `pacman` change according to `$MSYSTEM`?

Comment: `pacman` does not build packages, it just installs them.  You can run `pacman` just fine no matter what `$MSYSTEM` is set to, and `$MSYSTEM` does not affect it as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

> What are other significant differences determined by $MSYSTEM value?

For the record, the python `os.path.sep` is different, as explained here: https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/1591#issuecomment-573336696

This means that depending which shell you use, you will have path separated by `\` or `/` in your python paths.